# How to create mongodb collection on runtime while executing Yii2 code?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I need to create mongodb collection while executing code, by checking whether the collection is exists or not.

I tried below things

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()-> createCollection("collection_name");
```

but collection not created.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved..

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->createCollection("collection_name")->execute();
```

and index will added for collection as,

```
$collectionName = Yii::$app->db->getCollection("collection_name");
$collectionName->createIndexes([
'key' => ['id' => 'int'],
'name' => 'id_index'
],
[
'key' => ['id' => 'int', 'category' => 'text'],
'name' => 'id_category_index',
]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).